# Items collection must be empty after binding the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I fill the datagrid from SQLite database

```
var mA = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY Name", DataHolder.SQLiteConnection);
var mT = new System.Data.DataTable();
if (dataGrid.Columns.Count > 0)
{
  return;
}
mA.Fill(mT);
if (mT.Rows.Count == 0)
{
  mT.Rows.Add(new object[mT.Columns.Count]);
}
dataGrid.ItemsSource = mT.DefaultView;
```

but after I bind the `DataGrid` to change the cell background if its value equals 0 by that code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="0,10,0,0" Loaded="dataGrid_Loaded" FontSize="14">
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Active}">
      <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource All}}"/>
         </Style>
      </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
   </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

IValueConverter

```
public class All : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string input = value as string;    

        if (System.Convert.ToByte(input) == 0)
        {
            return Brushes.Red;
        }
        else if (System.Convert.ToByte(input) > 0 && System.Convert.ToByte(input) < 5)
        {
            return Brushes.OrangeRed;
        }
        else
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

I get that error at runtime when `DataGrid` is being filled that say

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Items collection must be empty before using
>   ItemsSource.

at `dataGrid.ItemsSource = mT.DefaultView;`

Comment: this error occurs when the control contains hard coded elements too. like add some comboboxitem to combobox and then set itemssource too, u will get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `DataGrid.Columns` tag in you XAML. Without that `DataGridTextColumn` is treated as an item and since you set `ItemsSource` you get an error that you try to fill items from two sources

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns> 
        <DataGridTextColumn>
```